# Difference between return function and call a function in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, function

I made a function to add a comment in posted article and I put that function in the `ArticlesController`. After calling that function in the end first I tried to return `show()` function for that specific article it worked then I tried to call it `$this->show('passing in params')` but calling the function gives me blank page I'm confused now is there any differences between calling and returning a function, which is the proper way of doing things like that?

```
class ArticlesController extends Controller
{
public function show(Article $article, Comment $comments)
{
    $comments = $article->comments;

    return view('articles.show', compact('article', 'comments'));
}
 public function addComment(Article $article, Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'comment' => 'required|min:3|max:255'
    ]);

    $comments = new Comment($request->all());

    $comments->article_id = $article->id;

    Auth::user()->comments()->save($comments);

    return $this->show($article, $comments);
}
```

> routes.php

```
<?php
Route::post('articles/{articles}', 'ArticlesController@addComment');
Route::resource('articles', 'ArticlesController');

Route::get('tags/{tags}', 'TagsController@show');
Route::controllers([
'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController'
]);
```

Comment: what is ` $this->show` does ?

Comment: why are you even passing $comment as parameter in show() when right below u override it with : $comments = $article->comments; ?

Comment: return $this->show($article, $comments); should give you the expected result.... there should be some other error...